# DataBase Structure and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Good Day Guys,

this might be a stupid question so sorry.

I have these tables.

**StockTransfer** 
`st_id`

**StockTransferDetails** `stDetails_id`,
`st_id`, `SourceLocation`, `DestinationLocation`

**InventoryLocation**
`LocationID`, `Description`

**Sample Result to be displayed: For Details**

`ItemID` = 1, `ItemCode` = 001, `ItemDesc` = sample item, `SourceLocation` = location1, `DestinationLocation` = location2..

1. **StockTransfer**
2. **StockTransfer Details**
3. **InventoryLocation**

I'm doing an Inner Join on `StockTransfer` and its `details`.

I can't do a join on `InventoryLocation`, since the `StockTransferDetails` have `SourceLocation` and `DestinationLocation` Fields. so to get the description of Source and Destination location I have to loop over the result and do a query twice on InventoryLocation which is I think is bad. Does it makes it slower?

My solution is to make a seperate table for the `SourceLocation` and `DestinationLocation` for me to Join them... Am I doing it right or the other way around.. I'm using `MSSql`

I need advice guys.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: Thanks. What's the output you want to see? I suspect you can join to `InventoryLocation` twice, once by `Source` and once by `Destination` to solve your issue.

Comment: @shree.pat18 what's your advice sir?

Comment: sample data for InventoryLocation table?

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều just a bunch of locations and ids.

Comment: which columns relate in those tables (`StockTransferDetails`, `InventoryLocation`)? `SourceLocation` vs `Description` or `DestinationLocation` vs `Description` or both `SourceLocation` and `DestinationLocation`  vs `Description`

Comment: Are you sure your InventoryLocation table has only 2 fields as you mentioned? "InventoryLocation LocationID, Description"

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều both `Source` and `Destination` came from `InventoryLocationID`

Comment: @Adish yes I am sure.

Comment: InventoryLocationId does not contain information about Inventory? only about location? Strange, to say the least.

Comment: I think your approach is OK if you are joining twice. What part are you worried about?

Comment: I got it... @shree.pat18 is right.... I never thought I can Join InventoryLocation Twice in StockTransfer Details using `SourceLocation` and `DestinationLocation`...  thanks

Comment: StockTransferDetails:
1 1 AA AB
InventoryLocation:
1 AA
2 AB
Your result like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them together, why not:

```
select * from
    StockTransferDetails a 
    left join InventoryLocation b on a.SourceLocation = b.Location_ID 
    left join InventoryLocation c on a.DestinationLocation = c.LocationID
```